# ARC enabled project with a non-ARC static library

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have a ARC enabled Mac project with a non-ARC enabled framework, all compiles fine but once run the non-ARC framework displays a form, however when you click a button, a error is thrown like...

```
2012-11-10 23:32:11.191 TestApp[20691:303] -[__NSCFType next:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101c13070
2012-11-10 23:32:11.193 TestApp[20691:303] -[__NSCFType next:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101c13070
2012-11-10 23:32:11.198 TestApp20691:303 doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8e63a5ce forwarding + 414
4 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff8e63a3b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff78a59 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342
6 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff788b7 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 85
7 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff787eb -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 138
8 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff76cd3 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1855
9 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff76521 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 504
10 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff75c9c -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 820
11 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff6d60e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
12 AppKit 0x00007fff8ff69744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
13 AppKit 0x00007fff8fe7f2fa -[NSApplication run] + 636
14 AppKit 0x00007fff8fe23cb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
15 AppSim 0x00000001000026f2 main + 34
16 libdyld.dylib 0x00007fff97c6c7e1 start + 0
17 ??? 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
```

Converting the main project to non-ARC the problem goes... what is causing the problem, and how do I get around it?

I rather not convert my existing project to use non-ARC...

Steps to reproduce problem...

Download "Sample Project for OS X Lion, ~250 KB" from

https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion

Convert the main project to ARC, point the line starting with ... [yt uploadVideoAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath to any mov file you have, then run.

Clicking cancel or sign-in will cause the error...

Comment: plz add your console output to show us WHAT selector it doesnt recognize

Comment: That is my entire console output, i do know that putting a break point  on a (IBAction)next:(id)sender never gets called and error occurs when button clicked, and as mentioned above when using non-ARC the action is fired without error

Comment: ah, something is not retaining the click target and so it gets deallocated. Non-ARC code converted to arc but there are many cases where it doesnt work -- @SlyRaskal's comment is important for you :)

Comment: In addition, this question has nothing to do with Xcode at all. Removed false tag.

Comment: The framework is fully non-ARC and main project is completely ARC so don't think its a case of disabling ARC for relevant classes as not dragged any files from the framework into my project i.e i'm only linking to the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code has a memory leak:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    ESSYouTube *yt = [[ESSYouTube alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                             developerKey:@""];
    [yt uploadVideoAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/path/to/mov"]];
}
```

`yt` is never released.

When you plug that leak, either by adding a `release` or by converting to ARC, you will get the crash because the `ESSYouTube` and `ESSYouTubeWindowController` instances have been deallocated while the UI is still on screen.

The sample code needs to be fixed, and `ESSYouTube` should either retain itself as long its UI is on screen, or it should tear down its UI upon deallocation.

Comment: Great thanks for your help, i noticed as a quick test removing the autorelease from self._ytWinCtr = [[[ESSYouTubeWindowController alloc] initWithDelegate:self videoURL:url] autorelease]; fixed the crash... now to refactor the code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a project that has ARC and non-ARC assets.  If you haven't already, I would set any classes that are not ARC enabled to not compile using ARC. Refer to here: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Dont think thats it, as mentioned above "The framework is fully non-ARC and main project is completely ARC so don't think its a case of disabling ARC for relevant classes as not dragged any files from the framework into my project i.e i'm only linking to the framework."

Comment: He mentions that the non-ARC code is in a static library. There are no individual class files to set to compile without ARC at that point, because they have already been compiled. (And presumably it was done without ARC.)